# What is an “synthetic paper”

Tags: publications, terminology

The Wikipedia page for “[Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)” has a section on ”[Synthetic papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#Synthetic_papers)”.

What precisely is a synthetic paper?

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://japan.yupo.com/english/product/paper/thing.html), but it is surprisingly both very precise and very unhelpful. :-)

Comment: You can generate a synthetic paper [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/archive/scigen/) but I think that is equally unhelpful. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *synthetic* can have different meanings. In this context the definition of the word "synthesis" is helpful:

> 1. The combining of separate elements or substances to form a coherent whole.
> 2. The complex whole so formed.

A synthetic paper is a paper that summarizes results and ideas from various origins to form a (hopefully) coherent statement or conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Synthetic papers are sort of critical reviews that describe important concepts in, often, multidisciplinary fields. These papers are often structured and written in a (slightly) different way than typical reviews (or normal papers).

For example, the synthetic papers in your post describe important concepts that link together mathematics, logic, and computation.